# How to ger $M\geqslant m$ with all that possibilities?

Tags: real-analysis

Let the following be given:

- $a,b,m$ positive constants
- $k_-,k_+\geqslant 0$ constants
- $r,s$ positive integers

I wonder if
$$
M:=\frac{m^rsk_+a+m^srk_-b}{m^{r-1} rk_+a+m^{s-1}s k_-b}\geqslant m.
$$

There are so many different possibilities that I think that one cannot answer it in general.

For example, suppose $0<m<1$. Then, $m^{r-1}\geqslant m^r$ and $m^{s-1}\geqslant m^s$.

Then one can have $r<s$ or $r\geqslant s$ and so on.

One can have $k_-<k_+$ or $k_-\geqslant k_+$.

Comment: Are you asking if values exist which make your defined M at least m, or if no matter what values are chosen, M is at least m?

Comment: the first question would be more interesting. but basically i would like to know both answers. for the second, i guess one can easily find counter examples

Comment: I don't have a formulation of which parameters make M>=m. However it would improve things if you gave some motivation, like what your inequality would be good for if it held.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\alpha:=m^{r-1}k_+a,\quad\beta:=m^{s-1}k_-b.$$
Then, $$M=\frac{ms\alpha+mr\beta}{r\alpha+s\beta}$$
hence
$$\begin{align}M\ge m&\iff\frac{s\alpha+r\beta}{r\alpha+s\beta}\ge1\\
&\iff s\alpha+r\beta\ge r\alpha+s\beta\\
&\iff(\alpha-\beta)(s-r)\ge0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. But shouldn't it be $(\alpha-\beta)(s-r)\geq 0$ where $\alpha:=m^r k_+ a$ and $\beta:=m^s k_-b$? Don't see why you have the exponents $r-1$ and $s-1$, respectively, in your definitions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: It wouldn't be not correct with your proposal, whereas it is with my definitions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I just added the details of the proof.